# JDialog dispose and repainting problem

Tags: performance, swing, concurrency, repaint, jdialog

In a jnlp application, we create a modal popup extends from javax.swing.JDialog, and call dispose() to hide the dialog whenever necessary. However, sometimes the final client get repainting problem. The dialog doesn't really disappear, and its parent window look messy. I couldn't reproduce, but it happen many times on final client PC. I guess there are 2 possible reasons:

- There is a thread in our application update the cursor directly. However, I can't prove this thread is the root cause of the issue.
- Periodically, we have another process highly use the CPU in a few seconds. I tried to load the CPU, but I couldn't reproduce the issue too.

Any advice for me in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: "Any advice for me in this case?"  I suggest you try to prepare an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) that shows the same behavior (though it is tricky in these situations of 'random error' combined with 'only appears on another machine').  There is very little information here that would indicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks the answer is in the question ;-)

Having a thread (**not the EDT**) updating the UI (the cursor in your case) may lead to this kind of problem.

Hence, ensure that your thread calls `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` (or `invokeAndWait()` depending on your needs).

Another possibility (but this depends a lot on what your thread does, without further description from your side, it is hard to tell) would be to use `SwingWorker` instead of a thread.

Comment: How can I ensure that thread is the root cause while I cannot reproduce? Is there anyway to force the issue happen more frequently?

Comment: No there's little chance that you could reproduce this kind of bug everytime as it depends on too many factors that cannot be mastered (typically, CPU load and thread scheduler).